# Lua - extract a string using patterns

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I'm just starting on Lua Patterns.

I have a string 
`|2|34|56|1`

How do I extract the numbers from the string?

I can parse the string manually and exclude all the '|' characters.  But I'm sure using Lua patterns will be much simpler.

How do patterns help in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to print those numbers, the best method is:

```
str = "|2|34|56|1"
str:gsub("%d+", print)
```

Else, if you want the numbers to be stored in a table, a longer approach is required:

```
str = "|2|34|56|1"
local tFinal = {}
str:gsub( "%d+", function(i) table.insert(tFinal, i) end)
table.foreach(tFinal, print)        -- This is only to verify that your numbers have been stored as a table.
```

Comment: Thanks! if some strings were present what would be the solution then?
Like `"|2|34|a|1|ba"`

Comment: NO. I mean if the string was `|2|34|a|1|ba`, I'd like to extract the strings as well.
I need to extract `2`,`34`,`"a"`,`1`,`"ba"`   Is that possible?

Comment: @SatheeshJM, use `"[^|]+"` instead of `"%d+"`.